# How to get expireAfterSeconds status of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The stats() function only list the "indexSizes" of each index,
but no expireAfterSeconds. How could I get this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongo shell you can use

```
db.collection.getIndexSpecs()
```

for it to show more information on the indices.

Somehow this functionality is not listed in the official document, 
or at least I can't find it. BTW, I'm using version 2.4.9